# Domain name migration: avoid phishing warnings

Tags: email, domain-name

I'm migrating email domains, so that all users will change from person@old.com to person@new.com

One thing we've discovered while testing is that certain email providers (especially Google) will put large warning banners on emails sent by these new email addresses that look like this:

[image: Screenshot of a warning stating 'Person has never sent you messages using this email address. Avoid replying to this email unless you reach out to the sender by other means to ensure that this email address is legitimate.']

This can cause confusion for clients receiving emails from us. Given this is on the receiver's end this is not a matter of us changing warning settings / allowlisting the new domain (we could ask all the people we email to do this, but this is infeasible in our case).

As a security measure, this makes sense given an attacker could register a domain similar and impersonate employee names and emails. However given in this case it is legitimate, is there any way to avoid these banners?

In my head I imagine the way to resolve this would be following some specification that looks something like putting a DNS record on old.com that tells services we have moved to new.com, and as such these banners should not appear. But I couldn't find anything along these lines easily.

Comment: Without knowing whether it's possible or would help, you can perhaps implement your idea with DKIM signatures? Perhaps if you place them with a selector of both domains, it will work? Really just spitballing here...

Comment: I don't think there is anything you can do here. This warning looks like it is shown along with every mail address that shows up the first time. If this is the case, no mechanism will prevent it.

Comment: TBH, I think warnings like this are a good thing. It reliably reduces the risk of phishing attempts by registering similar looking domains. Just inform your users about the new mail domain.